# Too many open files vol. II

Tags: java, linux, ulimit

we are facing issue on our JBoss server "too many open files".

Our ulimits for "appuser" are set to:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 46987
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 30000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Issues started with new version, where jboss is not started via sh script, but using system service. System service is run under the root user but application is started under "appuser".

I have checked lsoft output and I am not clever from this output (42777 is PID of our java process)

```
lsof | awk '{ print $2 " " $1; }' | sort -rn | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -20



261798 42777 default
  55071 42777 elasticse
  48049 42777 cluster-C
  19142 42777 java
  19117 42777 MSC
  12060 42777 ActiveMQ
   9609 42777 CleanCurs
   9570 42777 ServerSer
   7227 42777 managemen
   7203 42777 expiratio
   7173 42777 AsyncAppe
   7151 42777 Transacti
   4861 42777 pool-1154
   4849 42777 pool-1178
   4834 42777 pool-1122
   4811 42777 Deploymen
   4769 42777 VM
   4769 42777 Reference
   4760 42777 C2
   2432 42777 pool-1164
```

The result shows almost half milion of open files. How it is possible if limit is 30 000?

This command shows totaly different values of open files

```
ls -d /proc/[1-9]*/fd/*|cut -d/ -f3|sort |uniq -c |sort -rn|head

2743 42777
     91 1352
     51 1
     28 609
     19 861
     16 860
     16 844
     15 1090
     13 1098
     13 1097
```

When application start failing ls -d command return also around 2500 open files which is nothing with our limit set to 30000.

What we should check?

Thanks

Comment: You could start with checking actual file paths mentioned as open by your process (see lsof NAME column) as this often relates to sources of dodgy file handling which might be where your app is probably not using `try() {}` with resource handling or cleaning up after file access.

Comment: Thank you. Here really helped to set parameter LimitNOFILE=30000 to our starting service.